# Capitalization rules concerning historical time periods

Tags: grammar, capitalization, history

What are the capitalization rules concerning historical time periods? For example, how would I write:

> post-classical Europe

Is it:

> - "post-classical Europe"
> - "Post-Classical Europe"
> - "post-Classical Europe"

or none of the above?

Comment: Such matters are largely a question of style. Adhere to the discipline of your editor, publication, or organization, or in the absence of a house style, adopt a [style manual](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2579) appropriate to your audience and tastes and be consistent in its application.

Answer (score -1):

The **phrase** is "post-classical Europe," just an adjective-noun pair. When referring to the specific **term** (as in a case where it is defined earlier), use "Post-Classical Europe." You may never need "post-Classical Europe" for any purpose.

Note, of course, that in **titles**, initial capitals may be used in any case: "Chapter 5. Post-Classical Europe".